# What are precisley energy band extremes?

Tags: energy, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

So I've got an energy band that goes like
$$E(k)=E_0-t\cos(ak)$$
Now, I have to calculate the group velocity at the extrema of the band, but it's not clear to me what a band extreme is, and how to find it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Extrema=Max or Min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singular of 'extrema' is 'extremum', which means a point where a function reaches the extremes of its range, i.e. the term lumps together both maxima and minima.